VSCode GDB session cant find Intel Library
I am attempted to remotely debug a pice of Fortran code. On the system I have environment modules loaded for the Intel compilers. The code builds and runs fine in the terminal.
However when I try to run it with the GDB Debugger - beyond extension in VSCode I get the following error:
&"warning: GDB: Failed to set controlling terminal: Operation not permitted\n"
/home/co1f23/scratch/AQI_240831/AQI_240831: error while loading shared libraries: libimf.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

I have tried to set the environment variables to point to the right location for the library it cant find, but I still get the same error.
My launch.json looks like:
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "by-gdb",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch(gdb)",
            "program": "AQI_240831",
            "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
            "env":[{"name":"LD_LIBRARY_PATH", "value":"/local/software/gdb/13.2/lib:/mainfs/local/software/intel/2024.0.0/install/compiler/2024.0/lib:/local/software/gcc/12.2.0/libexec/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/12.2.0:/local/software/gcc/12.2.0/lib64:/local/software/gcc/12.2.0/lib:/local/software/slurm/default/lib"}],
            "externalConsole": true
        }
    ]
}

Does anyone know how to set the environemnt variables correctly in the launch.json so that they get picked up when launching the code with GDB?
